# Agent service running on VM, but shown as offline in DevOps Portal

Tags: azure-devops

I have installed the agent on my RHEL 7.5 box and can confirm that it is working.

```
etc/systemd/system/vsts.agent.sede\x2dds\x2dadp.CFS_POOL.PoCAgent.service
● vsts.agent.sede\x2dds\x2dadp.CFS_POOL.PoCAgent.service - Azure Pipelines Agent (sede-ds-adp.CFS_POOL.PoCAgent)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vsts.agent.sede\x2dds\x2dadp.CFS_POOL.PoCAgent.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-02-11 22:03:05 UTC; 16s ago
 Main PID: 7460 (runsvc.sh)
   CGroup: /system.slice/vsts.agent.sede\x2dds\x2dadp.CFS_POOL.PoCAgent.service
           ├─7460 /bin/bash /home/deploy/myagent/runsvc.sh
           ├─7463 ./externals/node/bin/node ./bin/AgentService.js
           └─7469 /home/deploy/myagent/bin/Agent.Listener run --startuptype s...

Feb 11 22:03:05 1167247-enlpoc.sga-res.com systemd[1]: Started Azure Pipeline...
Feb 11 22:03:05 1167247-enlpoc.sga-res.com systemd[1]: Starting Azure Pipelin...
Feb 11 22:03:05 1167247-enlpoc.sga-res.com runsvc.sh[7460]: .path=/usr/local/...
Feb 11 22:03:06 1167247-enlpoc.sga-res.com runsvc.sh[7460]: Starting Agent li...
Feb 11 22:03:06 1167247-enlpoc.sga-res.com runsvc.sh[7460]: Started listener ...
Feb 11 22:03:06 1167247-enlpoc.sga-res.com runsvc.sh[7460]: Started running s...
Feb 11 22:03:06 1167247-enlpoc.sga-res.com runsvc.sh[7460]: Scanning for tool...
Feb 11 22:03:06 1167247-enlpoc.sga-res.com runsvc.sh[7460]: Connecting to the...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Unfortunately the agent appears offline in the portal, only allowing me to run builds jobs by triggering the agent interactively.

This is similar to the issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/4215), which doesnt point to a resolution.

I would appreciate guidance on this

Comment: There is some diagnostic info in the ```_diag``` folder of the agent directory that might help you. Might also be worth seeking any similar issues on the agent github. https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues

Comment: Does what you want is run agent as service? Then it can be work fine from portal? Not too understand "only allowing me to run builds jobs by triggering the agent interactively.", do you mean interative mode agent can display and work fine?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT yes I want to run it as a service and followed the instructions from the portal to do so. I can see the service running, but the agent is offline in the portal. I can however run it interactively which doesn’t suit my use case

Comment: @EricSmith thanks will check once I am back at my desk

Comment: Which user type are you using when you run this agent as service? Root user? Or non-root user?

Comment: I have a non root user.. thought that was the issue but created a new user, added to the sudo group and still have the same issue

Comment: @SamuelDare. Nope. For linux agent, you should not run with root user while the agent running as service.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#run-as-a-systemd-service So, you means non-root user still could not available?

Comment: Yes .. always run it with a non-root user and it wasnt available

Comment: To be clear, by non root user means I need to use sudo to run prviledged commands?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exact same problem agent showing offline in Azure devops. The agent services show as  running in windows services.msc. My windows domain Logon password was change a while ago and I use same creds in logon info in agent services. Once the changed the logon password to current password, agent came online.

later I was advised to change logon creds to some local or service account and set password to never expire.

Both the above scenarios worked!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did `journalctl -x -u vsts.agent.service`
and in those logs I've seen it was complaining about storage issue.

If you don't know what is the service you need to check, you can run `svc.sh status` and it will run the systemctl status command for you and displaying it's name.
Or you can try `systmectl list-units | grep vsts`.